# Cannot filter RecyclerView using Spinner

Tags: android, string, arraylist, spinner, startswith

I'm an Android developer and I'm facing a kind of awkward situation here: I filled up a spinner with static values and I'm playing around with the items in the spinner to filter a list of strings made of static values as well (It's actually a list of countries from A-Z). The issue is with the filtering itself. Whenever I'm testing for the occurrence of a country in my list I keep on having false being returned. Here is the code:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Spinner mSpinner;
private List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
private TestCountriesAdapter adapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_country, container, false);

    countries = Arrays.asList(getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array));
// This List is Not Empty !!.. I already cross-checked over and over
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyler_view);
    mSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_projects);

    initRecyclerView();

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void initRecyclerView()
{
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapter = new TestCountriesAdapter(getActivity(), countries);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is the issue:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {



Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Size of List = " + countries.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 // Here again the List is Non-empty

    List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    switch (position)
    {
        case 1:
            for (String country: countries)
            {
                if (country.startsWith("A")
                        || country.startsWith("B")
                        || country.startsWith("C")
                        || country.startsWith("D")
                        || country.startsWith("E")
                        )
                    filteredList.add(country);

            }

            break;
        case 2:
            for (String country: countries)
            {
                if (country.startsWith("F")
                        || country.startsWith("G")
                        || country.startsWith("H")
                        || country.startsWith("I")
                        || country.startsWith("j")
                        )
                    filteredList.add(country);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for (String country: countries)
            {
                if (country.startsWith("K")
                        || country.startsWith("L")
                        || country.startsWith("M")
                        || country.startsWith("N")
                        || country.startsWith("O")
                        )
                    filteredList.add(country);
            }

           break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    countries = filteredList;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

In each of the "cases" whenever I do country.startsWith ("a letter"), I get false being returned.
I really don't know I keep on having this "false".
What did I do wrong ??...what was my mistake ??

Comment: where did you attach adapter with spinner ?

Comment: There might be issues with your data itself. Can you log both country and startsWith result ?

Comment: @ Adnan Ali....The values are declared in the string resource folder and i Just referenced it in the xml file.  The values in the spinner are there; I already tested it via Toast messages

Comment: Ashik Vetrivelu I already logged both the country and startsWith() method. If you check clearly you'll see I logged the country twice in my code.

Comment: Ashik Vetrivelu  As for the startsWith() it returns false in all the "cases" in the switch statements. BUT when I (log) do for Exemple: countries.get(0).startsWith("A") BEFORE ENTERING THE SWITCH statement it returns the (true) result

Comment: PB SOLVED !! It turns out all I needed to do was this:                                                  public void RefreshLayout(List<String> newDataSet)
    {
        countries = newDataSet;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }                                                                                                                                 and do this:                                                                                                                        adapter.RefreshLayout(filteredList);
 in each case after the for loop